# Specific placeholder ${...} in the header is being splitted

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I was trying to replace a placeholder in the header of my word document, but it fails when using `${someplaceholder}`:

```
 XDocument xDoc = docOriginal.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

 foreach (var headerPart in docOriginal.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
 {
     foreach (var currentText in headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<Text>())
     {
         Debug.WriteLine(currentText.Text);
        
        // works:
        // currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("SteuernummerPlatzhalterWert", "xSchmidtx");
         
         // doesn't work:
         currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("${SteuernummerPlatzhalterWert}", "xBlaBlax");
     }
 }
```

Below is a representation -

[image]
How to solve that problem?

Comment: After your first replace, the "${SteuernummerPlatzhalterWert}" has already changed to "${xSchmidtx}"

Comment: @KlausGütter, `${SteuernummerPlatzhalterWert}` is still split up in the original XML - word file (where no replacement took place), this is the reason `currentText.Text.Replace("${SteuernummerPlatzhalterWert}", ...` does not work. That current placeholder is encapsulated (split up) in different `Run`-Elements.